# How to create php response for requests.get of python script

Tags: php, python, server, get, python-requests

I would like to use this function in my Python script to take information from a PHP script, say from a variable in the script.

```
r = requests.get("http://jawad.meswatts.fr/sous/api.php")
```

api.php

```
<?php
    try
    {
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=jawad;charset=utf8', 'jawad', '************');
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
    }

    $req = $bdd->prepare( ' SELECT state FROM MOTOR ' );
    $req->execute(); 
    while ($donnees = $req->fetch())
    {
        $state = $donnees['state'];
    }
    $req->closeCursor();
?>
```

How to get the value of `$state` sent to the Python script via `requests.get`?

Comment: I need some help understanding what's going on here. What do you need help with exactly?  Do you need help with the PHP or the Python?  Is this really an HTTP request or are the PHP and the Python running on the same machine?  Give some more details about what you're trying to do here

Comment: no it is not in the same machine, i have a PHP script that is in a server, and the Python script that is on a raspberry the goal is that i use the request.get function in the script python for the api.PHP script to send me the value of "state"

Comment: So is the PHP not working or the Python script?

Answer (score 1):

You could make your php script return a string in JSON format. Then python would receive a string and could parse it into its own data structure. You might have to either `echo` or `return`your result.

PHP has a JSON object that can serialize arrays:
http://php.net/manual/de/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php

Python has a module JSON to decode a JSON string:

2.7: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

3.6: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html

Comment: thank you for your answer, but what I'm wondering is what the results we get in the variable R in case I do not want to use Json !  I know how to use the POST method to send data to my PHP script but if the GET method is supposed to be used to receive data via a URL address I do not understand how it's done

Comment: @jawaddidouh, as what he said, you have to either `echo` or `return` your result. In this case, you should probably do `echo $state;`. Just make sure that `$state`'s scope is not limited to your `while` loop.

Comment: My apologies (I can no longer edit my previous comment), I don't think it would be best to do just `echo $state`. Go with what Tekay37 has suggested by returning the values in JSON format.

Comment: okk i see ! but in many example a see code like this  : r = requests.get("http://linuxfr.org/")
print(r.text)    and they doesn't use json !  the problem is that they don't show what happen is the " information source side "

Comment: Yes, they either output data, that doesn't need to be parsed or they output data in an easy to parse way. It doesn't matter if you use json, yaml or xml for that matter. json is just a convenient way to do it.